# How to inject in a google chrome extension a CSS file on a page conditionally on extension storage data?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a popup settings page that is changing a boolean inside chrome.storage.sync to enabled/disabled based on a checkbox.

In my manifest I am adding page.js when matching to a specific page URL.
Inside this page.js how do I load a css file conditionally on that boolean inside the chrome.storage.sync?

I want to inject a file, not a css string... the examples show chrome.scripting.insertCSS with a string

Answer (score 0):

Visit https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#method-insertCSS
then click on CSSInjection link and read carefully

chrome.scripting.insertCSS(
injection: [CSSInjection](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#type-CSSInjection),
callback?: function
)